¿Cómo mapear dinámicamente una subclase de interfaz en un formulario Thymeleaf y enviarla al backend en Spring Boot?
Descripción:
Estoy trabajando en un formulario con Thymeleaf y Spring Boot para crear un objeto DeviceDto. Este DTO incluye un campo de configuración (DeviceConfig) que es una interfaz con dos posibles implementaciones: WifiConfig y BluetoothConfig. El tipo de configuración depende de un campo connectionType seleccionado en el formulario.
Formulario HTML
En el formulario, los campos específicos de configuración (como ssid, password y ipAddress para WiFi o deviceName para Bluetooth) deben mostrarse dinámicamente según la opción seleccionada en un .
<form action="#" th:action="@{/devices/new}" th:object="${device}" method="post">
    <label for="name">Device Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" required />

    <label for="connection-type">Connection Type</label>
    <select id="connection-type" th:field="*{connectionType}" onchange="handleTypeChange()" required>
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="WIFI">WiFi</option>
        <option value="BLUETOOTH">Bluetooth</option>
    </select>

    <div id="wifiFields" style="display:none;">
        <label for="ssid">SSID</label>
        <input id="ssid" type="text" th:field="*{deviceConfig.ssid}" class="form-control" />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" th:field="*{deviceConfig.password}" class="form-control" />

        <label for="ipAddress">IP Address</label>
        <input id="ipAddress" type="text" th:field="*{deviceConfig.ipAddress}" class="form-control" />

        <label for="channel">Channel</label>
        <input id="channel" type="number" th:field="*{deviceConfig.channel}" class="form-control" />

    </div>

    <div id="bluetoothFields" style="display:none;">
        <label for="deviceName">Device Name</label>
        <input id="deviceName" type="text" th:field="*{deviceConfig.deviceName}" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

    <script>
        function handleTypeChange() {
            const type = document.getElementById("connection-type").value;
            document.getElementById("wifiFields").style.display = type === "WIFI" ? "block" : "none";
            document.getElementById("bluetoothFields").style.display = type === "BLUETOOTH" ? "block" : "none";
        }
    </script>

Backend
El DTO en el backend se ve así:
public class DeviceDto {
    private String name;
    private String connectionType; // WIFI o BLUETOOTH
    private DeviceConfig deviceConfig; // Interfaz
}
Las implementaciones de la interfaz son:

public interface DeviceConfig {}

public class WifiConfig implements DeviceConfig {
    private String ssid;
    private String password;
    private String ipAddress;
    private int channel;
    private String securityType; // WPA2, WPA3, etc.

    // Getters y setters
}

public class BluetoothConfig implements DeviceConfig {
    private String deviceName;

    // Getters y setters
}

En el controlador, estoy intentando capturar el formulario así:
@PostMapping("/devices/new")
public String saveDevice(@ModelAttribute("device") DeviceDto deviceDto) {
    // Procesar el DTO y guardar
    System.out.println(deviceDto);
    return "redirect:/devices";
}

Problema
No sé cómo mapear correctamente el campo deviceConfig dependiendo del valor de connectionType seleccionado en el formulario. Actualmente, siempre es null en el backend.
¿Cómo puedo lograr que los campos específicos de configuración se mapeen dinámicamente a la implementación correcta (WifiConfig o BluetoothConfig) y se envíen correctamente al backend?
La objetivo de todo esto al final del dia es poder crear distintos devices y que cada uno pueda definir los campos necesarios para su configuraciones, luego lo que tengo que pensado es crear estrategias para utilizar cada tipo de Device que exista
Esto es lo que principalmente se me habia ocurrido y queria tratar de hacerlo de la forma con mejores practicas posibles pero si existe otra forma mas comun para tratar este tipo de problemas, tambien acepto sugerencias
Dato adicional estoy usando mongodb y es un requerimiento que se use si o si esta base de datos, asi que estaba pensando almacenar los devices y al guardar el config de cada device, embeber el config con sus campos correspondientes (sin crear otra coleccion)
Aca pongo un ejemplo de como deberia quedar la db con dos archivos
{
  "_id": "device1",
  "name": "Home Router",
  "connectionType": "WIFI",
  "deviceConfig": {
    "type": "WifiConfig",
    "ssid": "HomeWiFi",
    "password": "12345678",
    "ipAddress": "192.168.0.1"
  }
}

y en caso que se otro tipo de config
{
  "_id": "device2",
  "name": "Bluetooth Speaker",
  "connectionType": "BLUETOOTH",
  "deviceConfig": {
    "type": "BluetoothConfig",
    "deviceName": "Speaker123"
  }
}

Habia llegado a encontrar una posible solucion usando esto en mi DeviceConfig
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
    property = "connectionType"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WifiConfig.class, name = "WIFI"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BluetoothConfig.class, name = "BLUETOOTH")
})
public interface DeviceConfig{
    // Interfaz vacía para polimorfismo
}

Sin embargo no pude entenderlo ni conceptualmente ni tampoco pude implementarlo, cuando veo lo que llega al backend es un DeviceDto con el name que se puso en el formulario, un connectionType que tambien es correcto pero el deviceConfig en null
Desde ya agradezco cualquier respuesta y orientacion
